# Expo Router V2 going to [...missing] route

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo-router

I am implementing an authentication flow with `Firebase-Auth` using `Expo-Router-v2`. I've followed the tutorial [here](https://dev.to/aaronksaunders/expo-router-v2-authentication-flow-with-appwrite-jee) (replacing AppWrite with Firebase-Auth).

However, when I have a user authenticated  and reload the application it redirects me to the Missing Route Page. Although, this doesn't happen when I go through the flow of creating a user.

### _layout.jsx

```
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { Provider, useAuth } from "../context/auth";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "(tabs)/home",
};

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <RootLayoutNav />
    </Provider>
  );
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const { authInitialized, user } = useAuth();
  if (!authInitialized && !user) return null;
  if (authInitialized) {
    SplashScreen.hideAsync();
  }
  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ animation: "none" }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="(create-account)"
        options={{ presentation: "fullScreenModal" }}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

### auth.jsx (Auth Context)

```
import { useRootNavigation, useRouter, useSegments } from "expo-router";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "../config/firebase";
import {
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInAnonymously,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export function Provider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [authInitialized, setAuthInitialized] = useState(false);

  const useProtectedRoute = (user) => {
    const segments = useSegments();
    const router = useRouter();

    const [isNavigationReady, setNavigationReady] = useState(false);
    const rootNavigation = useRootNavigation();

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = rootNavigation?.addListener("state", (event) => {
        setNavigationReady(true);
      });
      return function cleanup() {
        if (unsubscribe) {
          unsubscribe();
        }
      };
    }, [rootNavigation]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isNavigationReady) {
        return;
      }

      const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === "(auth)";

      if (!authInitialized) return;
      // SUSPECTED ISSUE HERE? AS NO USE CASE FOR (USER && !INAUTHGROUP)
      if (!user && !inAuthGroup) {
        router.push("/(auth)/onboard");
      } else if (user && inAuthGroup) {
        router.push("(tabs)/home");
      }
    }, [user, segments, authInitialized, isNavigationReady]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
        setAuthInitialized(true);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setAuthInitialized(true);
      }
    });
    return () => subscriber();
  }, []);

  const appSignInAnonymously = async () => {
    try {
      await signInAnonymously(FIREBASE_AUTH);
    } catch (error) {
      setUser(null);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const appSignInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        FIREBASE_AUTH,
        email,
        password
      );
      setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      setUser(null);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const appSignOut = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut(FIREBASE_AUTH);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } finally {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  useProtectedRoute(user);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        appSignInAnonymously,
        appSignInWithEmailAndPassword,
        appSignOut,
        user,
        authInitialized,
      }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useAuth = () => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!authContext) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthContextProvider");
  }
  return authContext;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because you don't have a index file in your app folder so create a index and use Redirect with an auth user variable to check if the user is logged or not to redirect to login or home screen.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'expo-router'
import { useAuth } from '@/context/Authprovider'
import { MontserratText } from '@/components/StyledText';

const index = () => {
  
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth.isLoading) {
    return <MontserratText >Loading...</MontserratText>;
  }

  if (!auth.session) {
    return <Redirect href="/(auth)/login" />;
  }

  return  <Redirect href="/(tabs)/home" />;
}

export default index
```